# How can I delete the root node of a LDAP tree?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I would like to restore a LDAP tree with `slapadd` from a backup generated with `slapcat`. When I load the backup on a freshly installed OpenLDAP instance, `slapadd` complains about the root node already existing. I know about the `slapadd` `-c` option that continues on errors, but I would like to do things properly and not generate false negatives.

So before I call `slapadd` I would like to delete the root node:

```
ldapdelete -W -x -H ldapi:/// -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=tld "dc=mydomain,dc=tld"
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_delete: No such object (32)
```

What am I doing wrong with this command? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Have you considered not trying to restore the root node / deleting the root node from the backup?  As I recall, an LDAP backup is something like LDIF, which is often largely represented as ascii text and quite editable. (It has been quite a while though).

Comment: This is conceivable. This backup/restore context is fully automatized so I would like to stick to simple commands, but I suppose editing a ldif is simple enough.